# Levelplot with incomplete data

Tags: r

Using the lattice package in R:

I have let myself deeply into a rabbit hole and now I need some help to get out.

I have some (expensive) data points that naturally live on a 32x32 grid but I don't have all the possible data points

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   53 obs. of  3 variables:
$ X: num  16 16 16 16 13 13 13 13 23 23 ...
$ Y: num  20 16 23 10 16 23 20 10 16 23 ...
$ Z: num  1558 1561 1555 1540 1538 ...
```

When I try to use `levelplot` like this,

```
> levelplot(data$Z ~ rbind(data$X, data$X) * rbind(data$Y, data$Y), 
     xlim=c(0.5, 32.5), ylim=c(0.5, 32.5))
```

the plot has the colored patches clustered in a (for me) confusing way. [Output from levelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fKTk.png)

What I would like to achieve is that I have one colored patch per 1-by-1 index pair corresponding to my data. Absent grid points can be left white.

I tried to understand the R documentation but have given up.

Further, I have tried a grid with dummy `NA`, and then tried filling out the relevant data points. Something like

```
> x <- seq(1, 32, length.out=32)
> y <- seq(1, 32, length.out=32)
> data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
> data$Z <- NA
> tmp <- res[selected_data, ]
> data[(data$X == tmp$X) & (data$Y == tmp$Y), 'Z'] <- tmp$Z
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, (data$X == tmp$Input_Channel) & (data$Y ==  : 
replacement has 53 rows, data has 1024
```

Where `res` is the source of data points and `selected_data` is a vector of logicals used to select data from `res`. Anyway, this doesn't work.

Regardless, trying to make this latter approach work has been a wrong turn. I'd rather have a proper solution with `levelplot` rather than my failed work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution which I share to help others:

```
> dataX <- c(seq(1, 32), rep(1, 32), tmp$X)
> dataY <- c(rep(1, 32), seq(1, 32), tmp$Y)
> dataZ <- c(rep(NA, 64), tmp$Z)
> levelplot(dataZ ~ dataX * dataY)
```

Adding the `NA`s in this manner gives the desired output. [Desired output from levelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL7tc.png)